# Cause of desktop computer AC plug melting?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, desktop-computer

We discovered the family desktop computer's 110V AC cord to be swollen and hard to unplug from the PC. Both the plug and the receptacle are partially melted on what I think is the "hot" side (rather than the neutral side).

What is the cause for this? Are the PC components simply drawing more amps than the power supply can provide, or is the power supply malfunctioning? If the former, shouldn't the power supply have blown a fuse? When we upgraded the graphics card, we installed a power supply that was at least what the manufacturer recommended. Is there a way to know this won't happen again if I upgrade the power supply?

Here are pictures of the receptacle and plug:
[image]
[image]

Comment: A picture would be helpful.

Comment: Good idea. Added.

Comment: Low quality or defective cord did not have proper contact to blade in socket. Replace both cord and Power Supply Unit (PSU). In a related instance this was a common issue with HP printers at a certain point in time and the cords were recalled and hopefully replaced before they damaged the socket. The blade in the socket is burned and will ruin a new power cord in a short period of time.

Answer (score 7):

This *can* be caused by a multitude of problems, but chances are it is nothing serious.

One problem that happens with mains electrical contacts is when you have a slightly marginal connection (or vibration) which causes a slight spark. This spark causes a tiny amount of heat and burns off a piece of the electrical contact and often a tiny bit of the surrounding plug material.

This spark makes the contact slightly worse which just causes more sparks which causes more heat and it's just a vicious circle.

This could well have been started by a slightly dirty contact on either the plug or socket side. A bit of moisture getting in might have done this as well.

Chances are that this has not done any real damage to the power supply itself but I have to say that there is a **very** slim chance it has, most power supplies electrical safety certification requires that they be able to withstand small transients as would happen with this kind of electrical spark.

I would simply replace the lead, clean the power supply connector (replacing if possible) and make sure that the new lead makes good **firm** contact and because the degradation process has already started it may be worth replacing that power supply sooner rather than later.

If you feel confident replacing the connector itself (the PSU *should* be fine) then you should know that they are [common as muck](http://uk.farnell.com/volex/17252a-0-b1/connector-power-inlet-c14-receptacle/dp/1698584), reasonably cheap and easy to replace.